# SoftDelete Behavior CakePHP - delete Problems

Tags: cakephp, soft-delete

I'm using the Soft Delete - Behavior from CakeDC's utils package.
(https://github.com/CakeDC/utils)

Now the problem is: i want to check in the controller if something was soft(deleted), like this:

```
<?php
  if ($this->User->delete($id)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('user has been deleted'));
  } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('user has not been deleted'));
  }
 ?>
```

unfortunately i'm getting the results wrong. means that if the user was (soft)deleted i'll get 'user has not been deleted' messages and vice-versa.

I know how Cake handles this request and the beforeDelete hook must return false, to stop (hard) deleting the data. but referring to this [issue](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/issues/19) on github this should be fixed by now.
Am i the only one where this does not work?

Is there any other workaround for this problem, except for simply negating the condition? (don't want to do that, it just isn't right)

greetings and thanks in advance!
nahri

Comment: you might be interested that I started a discussion on this topic at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/cakephp-core/2vIZN8Sq8RE a few days ago. unfortunately without much response so far...

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I use for this is half copied and half written from the thread that @mark linked to.

Add this into your `AppModel`

```
/**
 * Override the delete() model method so that we can account for the
 * SoftDelete behaviours return
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @param bool $cascade
 * @return bool
 */
    public function delete($id = null, $cascade = true) {
        $result = parent::delete($id, $cascade);
        if ($result === false && $this->Behaviors->enabled('SoftDelete')) {
            return $this->field('deleted', array('deleted' => 1));
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Do bear in mind with this snippet that it uses the behaviours `default` settings. Which is why I use `'deleted' => 1` if you've named your field differently, then you'll want to change this.